# SQL Check constraint for an ID Number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to do a SQL Check Constraint for an ID number that is

```
Name: EmployeeID
Data Type: char
Size: 10
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am having trouble understanding how it takes some SQL commands that would work in a query, but not as a check constraint for some reason.

I am trying to do it using LIKE, such as

```
EmployeeID LIKE '[0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9]'
```

But it does not accept this, is there a better way to go about such a constraint?

Thank you.

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: SQL-Server says something like, "Error validating constraint, want to edit?"

Comment: If it's a **number** - then why are you storing it as `char(10)` ?!?!? If you would make this an `INT` - no check constraint necessary - only a number can be stored...

Comment: Also, are the spaces between the brackets in your actual code? Because that could be what's messing it up.

Comment: @marc_s - if it's a *string* composed of digits (including, possibly, leading zeros) and you have no intention of performing mathematics on it, why would you store it as a *number*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: just because - at some point - suddenly you **will** need to *add 5 to the EmployeeID* or *give me all employee with an ID between 15000 and 19999* or something like that - trust me! Also: a `INT` takes 4 bytes - `CHAR(10)` 10 bytes ....

Comment: @marc_s - and the possibility of leading zeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No spaces between the square brackets and it should work:

```
EmployeeID LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constraint currently requires 9 spaces to exist. Try:

```
EmployeeID LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Or maybe:

```
LEN(EmployeeID) = 10 and EmployeeID not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Which says that no character is outside the group of `0-9` and that it's 10 characters in length - more maintainable if the length needs to change in future.

Comment: Okay, I see. No spaces for it, the little details will be the death of me! :D Thank you!